# .swf into a html file. 5secs later will dissapear so that the html will appear

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I want to make div into my intex.htm file (already built site) to place in a .swf file that will cover the whole screen, and a few seconds later the animated page will disapear and the htm page will appear. I don't want to make different htm file, neither put a button on flash(ie on click...). I just want after a few seconds and after the flash has ended, the flash will go away and the page will appear.

Comment: That's great.  Now... what was the question?

Comment: Let's see if I'm getting this right: You have a SWF embedded in an HTML page. The SWF runs some sort of animation and when it ends, you want the SWF to be hidden (and some other content else in the HTML page to be shown)?

Comment: i haven t embedded the SWF in the HTML page yet. I ve been asked to put one that will cover the whole screen and when the animation ends, the HTML page - that has already been built - will appear. I ve been asked not to put a button (like ie skip intro), nor not to put the SWF in a diffenrent page ( ie not to put actionscript that would link to the HTML page), but just to use the index.html file that i've been given.
I hope I wasnt confusing :S

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)...

```
<html>
<head>
 ...
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var flash_time = 5000;//in ms
   $('#flash').delay(flash_time).hide();
   $('#cont').delay(flash_time).show();
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id='cont' style='display:none;'>
  ...content...
 </div>
 <div id='flash' style='width:100%;height:100%;'>
  ...embed...
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```